# how to find files copied in ubunut in NTFS drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, fat32

if I copied the file from the Ubuntu system to a passport with NTFS type, is there any solution to find the files I copied as the types are different or it is not copied as the sequence i did is

I transferred big files with size 1.5T and my passport's size is 2 T and I just copied the files into my passport until finished then check if there is already copied to the passport or not and I saw the files exist then after plugging out the cable of passport to check it again I couldn't mount the passport

but I used this command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

and successfully can open the passport but the files do not exist and there are important files to me and I couldn't get it again, please is there any solution

Does the orange color in this image

[image]

mean that the size of the passport has files I mean is there no space in the passport?

Comment: Did you use the "Eject" or "Unmount" from the right click menu and wait till it said it was safe to remove the drive?

Comment: i couldn't remember but i couldn't open the passport to check again and got `NTFS — Not Mounted` as when i right-click to unmount or remove safe i think it didn't work with me so i plug out the cable

Comment: `ntfsfix` merely signals the partition to be checked and corrected by Windows tools. Unlike it name suggests it fixes nothing because NTFS CAN'T be fixed in anything other than Windows OS, as I already told you.

Comment: excuse me what is the orange color mean in the image i attached

Comment: @ChanganAuto i tried to use Windows to open the passport but the files aren't exist

Comment: With such large size copy you have to give it time to unmount / eject until it is safe to remove. Ubuntu keeps the files in cache and copies them at its convenience. So even if it looks like the files are copied they are not. You have to wait till it is **safe to remove**.

Comment: *so i plug out the cable* < Very likely the file system is corrupt now. So, again, find yourself a Windows machine to *try* to correct the file system. The chances of recovering data are very low, keep that in mind, but learn about and understand about everything I commented before in your now deleted question.

Comment: if ntfsfix works with window , can i recover the files to be opened in ubuntu ?

Comment: No, `ntfsfix` is NOT from Windows.

Comment: Do you mean now that the files need to recover or  not exist, please?

Comment: excuse me what is the orange color means in the image i attached , does  the passport contains files or not

Comment: Reformat your USB drive and copy again. **Don't forget to Unmount** and **Wait for "Safe to Remove"** notification.

Comment: @user68186 excuse me what is the orange color means in the image i attached, does the passport contains files or not

Comment: Honestly you have more concerning issues to be worried about then colors that mean nothing.

Comment: The orange color in Gnome Disks indicate the selected partition. In your case it is `/dev/sdc1`. Since that is the only partition it is always selected and thus orange. It says nothing about if the files exist or not. Since the partition can't be mounted anymore, there is no way to find out how many of your files exist if any. Yanking the USB cable probably corrupted the partition table. It is all gone. Moral of the story: **Don't yank USB cables** (prematurely).

Comment: As soon as your copying to the drive is done, open a Terminal window and type in `sync` so that it will flush all the data to the drive(s).  When the prompt comes back, then you can safely remove the drive.

Comment: If you think the answer below is correct, please click on the gray check mark ✓ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved and help others.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i forgot to accept it and i will try it next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you yanked out the USB cable connecting the external hard drive to the computer without properly "ejecting" or "unmounting" the drive, the file system is probably corrupted.

This happens because Ubuntu (Linux in general) does not immediately copy the files to the external hard drive and keeps them in the cache even when it says all the files have been copied. Before you unplug the USB drive you have to tell Ubuntu to empty the cache and copy all the files. You do this by pressing the "Eject" or the "Unmount" option from the menu.

Ubuntu will then tell you when it is **safe to unplug**.

A healthy USB drive in Disks would look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the partition type and contents mention NTFS format.

Your USB drive seems unformatted based on the partial picture you have posted.

## Format the Drive

Click on the "Gears" icon and select **Format Partition...**:

[image]

- If you intend to use it only with Ubuntu, that select the format type as `ext4`.
- If you intend to use the drive with both Ubuntu and Windows then select `NTFS`.

## Copy the files again

Make sure the copying is completed and the "pie chart" icon gets full and disappears.

[image]

## Safely Remove Drive

Right click on the External Drive on the left panel of Nautilus and select **Safely Remove Drive**:

[image]

You may also click on the **Eject** icon next to the Drive Name. Or Right click on the USB Drive icon on the Dock and select "Unmount".

Wait till you see something like this in the Notification:

[image]

**Only unplug the USB cable after you see this notification above.**

Hope this helps